# How to parse xml data returned from alexa api in php?

Tags: php, xml

I am working with Alexa XML API to get website traffic rank data. I am using following api request to get information about a website say facebook.com:

```
http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url==www.facebook.com
```

I am receiving following xml data:

```
<!-- Need more Alexa data?  Find our APIs here: https://aws.amazon.com/alexa/ 
-->
<ALEXA VER="0.9" URL="facebook.com/" HOME="0" AID="=" IDN="facebook.com/">
  <RLS PREFIX="http://" more="0">
    <RL HREF="www.zynga.com/" TITLE="Zynga Inc."/>
    <RL HREF="www.zoominfo.com/" TITLE="ZoomInfo"/>
    <RL HREF="www.zoho.com/" TITLE="Zoho"/>
    <RL HREF="www.ziply.com/" TITLE="Ziply"/>
    <RL HREF="www.zillow.com/" TITLE="Zillow"/>
    <RL HREF="www.ziki.com/" TITLE="Ziki.com"/>
    <RL HREF="www.zazzle.com/" TITLE="Zazzle, Inc."/>
    <RL HREF="www.youtube.com/" TITLE="YouTube"/>
    <RL HREF="www.yonja.com/" TITLE="Yonja"/>
    <RL HREF="www.yelp.com/" TITLE="Yelp"/>
  </RLS>
  <SD TITLE="A" FLAGS="" HOST="facebook.com">
    <TITLE TEXT="Facebook"/>
    <OWNER NAME="TheFacebook, Inc."/>
  </SD>
  <SD>
    <POPULARITY URL="facebook.com/" TEXT="3" SOURCE="panel"/>
    <REACH RANK="3"/>
    <RANK DELTA="+0"/>
    <COUNTRY CODE="US" NAME="United States" RANK="3"/>
  </SD>
</ALEXA>
```

I am trying to parse this xml data with the help of a function simplexml_load_file() but it doesn't seem working.

My code:

```
function alexa_rank($url){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=".$url);
    if(isset($xml->SD)):
        return $xml->SD->POPULARITY->attributes();
    endif;
}

$url = "www.facebook.com";
echo alexa_rank($url);
```

I am getting following error:

```
 Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__toString(): Node no longer exists...
```

But when I remove extra attribute "`&dat=snbamz`" from the query string, then it works. Why?

Comment: What do you actually want from the XML, the problem is that your returning the attributes of POPULARITY, do you want all the values or just one value?

Comment: I want all node values/attributes from above xml. I want it in the same way like we parse values from json objects after converting into php array first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 `<SD>` elements in the XML and `<POPULARITY>` is only defined in the second one.  If this is always going to be the case, then you can change your return to

```
return $xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY->attributes();
```

(As arrays start at 0, `[1]` will return the second element.)

If you don't know when/where it may be, you should use XPath to find it...

```
$popularity = $xml->xpath("//SD/POPULARITY")[0];
```

The second part is that your returning a list of SimpleXMLElements, so it may be easier to use `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` to transform the data into an array.  So I would suggest you use this code...

```
function alexa_rank($url){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=".$url);
    $popularity = $xml->xpath("//SD[POPULARITY]")[0];
    return json_decode(json_encode($popularity),true);
}

$url = "www.facebook.com";
print_r( alexa_rank($url));
```

(Use `print_r()` as you have an array coming back from `alexa_rank()`)

For the data you gave above, this outputs...

```
Array
(
    [POPULARITY] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [URL] => facebook.com/
                    [TEXT] => 3
                    [SOURCE] => panel
                )

        )

    [REACH] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [RANK] => 3
                )

        )

    [RANK] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [DELTA] => +0
                )

        )

    [COUNTRY] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [CODE] => US
                    [NAME] => United States
                    [RANK] => 3
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Ok, I will try this code soon, well is this the only way to sort it out. Do we have other options too? What's about ParseXml.class.php?